# How to generate 200 random subgroups of size 10 from a N(80, σ=15) distribution in Python

Tags: python

I am looking to generate these random numbers but I am confused on how to do it, given a specificed mean and standard deviation?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [numpy.random.normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)

The `loc` and `scale` parameters are used to set the mean and deviation respectively, example:

```py
import numpy
numpy.random.normal(loc=80.0, scale=15.0, size=10)
"""
[ 89.65044376  71.82323775  76.76028318  53.43143287  74.62684553
  96.65651307  96.69405194 100.52626418  96.62026183  67.01384232]
"""
```